# Add-in disappearing from customers' ribbon in Word desktop

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, ribbonx

We are getting an increased number of reports from customers that our add-in sporadically disappear from the ribbon in Word. It is a problem for us as people don't use what they can't see and many are very un-tech savvy and don't know how to reactivate add-ins (especially if they are used to have their central admin push them out to them).

Is this a known issue? Is there any setting in the manifest file that we might have missed? We would appreciate any information that might point us in the right direction to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd suggest making sure the add-in is available and loaded by host application.

Second, I'd recommend checking whether any ribbon UI errors are thrown by the host application. By default, if an add-in attempts to manipulate the Microsoft Office user interface (UI) and fails, no error message is displayed. However, you can configure Microsoft Office applications to display messages for errors that relate to the UI. You can use these messages to help determine why a custom ribbon does not appear, or why a ribbon appears but no controls appear.

To show add-in user interface errors you need to start the application and configure the following option:

1. Click the File tab.
2. Click Options.
3. In the categories pane, click Advanced.
4. In the details pane, select `Show VSTO Add-in user interface errors`, and then click `OK`.

See [How to: Show Add-in user interface errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-show-add-in-user-interface-errors?view=vs-2022) for more information.